# Interactive 3d in the shape of js frameworks

Tags: javascript, web, 3d, three.js

I'm planning on creating an interactive 3d application in js. My question is whether or not babylon.js or three.js supports interactivity? Can't seem to find any information on this, and the documentation doesn't help much either.

Note; by interactivity, I mean for the user to be able to draw elements on a given 3d scene.

Comment: In sense you've mention three.js supports interactivity.

Comment: _"three.js supports interactivity"_, when you implement it in your code

Comment: "draw elements" can mean anything from "drawing a line" to full-blown 3D modeling. The first is trivial, the latter is a lifetime of work (and might benefit from writing the rendering engine from scratch). You need to ask a very specific question to get useful answers from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for babylon.js as I've never used it, but I do have some experience with three.js.

If by "draw elements" you mean creating or manipulating shapes/geometries on the fly based on user-input, then the following examples should prove that its definitely possible.

For instance, [on the three.js docs page](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CylinderGeometry), there is a control-panel used for manipulating a CylinderGeometry() object in the top-right corner of the live-example.

An example of "drawing" from cursor-input using raycasting can be found on [thee.js's examples page](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=rayc#webgl_interactive_raycasting_points) as well as [another example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cube#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes) where objects within the scene are draggable.

To be honest, the interactivity of your app is only limited by you.